# NodeJS ORM framework that updates migrations files from Model definitions

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, adonis.js

I am trying to set up a `NodeJS` backend with a `MySQL` database. I want to eventually containerize the database and containerize the backend server. To containerize the database, I need migration files.

I am looking for a framework that handles the generation of these migrations well. I have tried `Sequelize`, but you couldn't update your migrations based on your models.

I wanted to use `AdonisJS` but it was a full `MVC framework`, while the goal is to use it alongside `Express`.

Am I thinking the wrong way here?

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can generate migrations from models in sequelize using [sequelize-auto-migrations](https://github.com/flexxnn/sequelize-auto-migrations#readme).